# AWS Elastic Beanstalk worker process leaves SQS message in flight

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a NodeJS Elastic Beanstalk worker tier environment which takes messages from an SQS queue and posts them to an external url. The code below works as expected, but the message remains "in flight" in SQS. I can't see any documentation about how I inform SQS the message has been processed successfully?

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require("request"),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    req.on('data', function (data) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

        log("Processing " + jsonString);

        request.post('http://example.com', {
            json: true,
            body: jsonString,
            headers: {  
                "content-type": "application/json",
            }
        }, (error, res, body) => {
            if (error) {
                log(`Error ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            returnResponse(res, JSON.stringify(body));
        })
    });
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

function returnResponse(httpResponse, message) {
    log(`Response status code  ${httpResponse.statusCode} - ${message}`);
    httpResponse.writeHead(httpResponse.statusCode);
    httpResponse.write(message);
    httpResponse.end();
}

var log = function (entry) {
    fs.appendFileSync('/tmp/output.log', new Date().toISOString() + ' - ' + entry + '\n');
};
```

Comment: No, this is the correct code. The code is configured as a worker tier environment within Elastic Beanstalk. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fixed code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    request = require("request"),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    req.on('data', function (data) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

        log("Processing " + jsonString);

        request.post('http://example.com', {
            json: true,
            body: jsonString,
            headers: {  
                "content-type": "application/json",
            }
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                log(`Error ${error}`);
                return;
            }

            returnResponse(res, response.statusCode, JSON.stringify(body));
        })
    });
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

function returnResponse(res, statusCode, message) {
    log(`Response status code  ${statusCode} - ${message}`);
    res.writeHead(statusCode, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write('Complete');
    res.end();
}

var log = function (entry) {
    fs.appendFileSync('/tmp/sample-app.log', new Date().toISOString() + ' - ' + entry + '\n');
};
```

From https://www.edureka.co/blog/aws-elastic-beanstalk/

> The daemon pulls requests sent from an Amazon SQS queue. Based on the queue’s priority, SQS will send the message via a POSTrequest to the HTTP Path of the Worker Environment. The worker on receiving the message executes the tasks and sends an HTTP response once the operation is done. SQS on receiving response message deletes the message in the queue. If it fails to receive a response, it will continuously retry sending the messages.

The issue was that my previous code wasn't correctly returning an http status code.

Answer (score 0):

Message being **in flight** means that it was consumed by a consumer, but not yet deleted from the queue. If it's not deleted by the consumer during queue's **visibility timeout**, it will be put back into the queue by SQS again.

You should delete messages from the queue if you successfully process them. If you are familiar with AMQP 0-9-1, this action is similar to *acknowledging messages*.

Since, you are using Node.js, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#deleteMessage-property) is the method from official SDK, that you should use to achieve your goal.